# jquery find() ie8 issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am using jquery find function. this is working in firefox, chrome browser, but not working in IE8 & IE7.

```
var res= "<result><evento><name>hola</name></evento><evento><name>mundo</name></evento></result>"; 

    $(res).find("name").each(function() {
      alert(' userlist');
    });
```

Comment: `<name>` is not a standard HTML tag. See what happens if you make a new `<script>` block in the `<head>` that does this: `document.createElement("name");`

Comment: but this tag clearly working for chrome and firefox.

Comment: We need more information like what `res` is and if you really have `name` elements in your HTML, which would not be good, especially for older browsers.

Comment: Non-standard will mean it will work in some browsers but not others.

Comment: @Pointy ↑ means your selector is for searching tags. If you want to select classes you should type ".name"... look for jquery selectors.

Comment: What is `res`? What is `name`? Show us your object/array/var that contains this information.

Comment: I will show the meaning of res and name tag.

Answer (score 3):

It's XML! Therefore use [`parseXML`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/) to parse it.

```
var xml = $.parseXML("<result><evento><name>hola</name></evento><evento><name>mundo</name></evento></result>");

$(xml).find("name").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FLxH6/)

Comment: Object doesn't support this property or method error will be declared in parse xml.

Answer (score 1):

convert to xml type. automatically parsing

```
var res= "<result><evento><name>hola</name></evento><evento><name>mundo</name></evento></result>"; 

        $(text2XML(res)).find("name").each(function() {
          alert(name);
        });

    function text2XML(txt)
    {
        var xmlDoc;
        if (window.DOMParser)
        {
            xmlDoc=(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
        }
        else
        {
            xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async="false";
            xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
        }
        return xmlDoc;
    }
```